# How can I load a ul from another webpage into a div using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Okay, I feel like I'm close to getting it. I have two pages that are almost identical. One has a list of the alphabet and when a letter is chosen, the other page filters results (last names of people being queried from a database using php) and displays them on the right side of the screen. I am trying to pull in the ul from my second page that has the results into a div in the first page so that the second page does not have to be loaded.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".toggleLetters").click(function() {
      /* grabs URL from HREF attribute then adds an  */
      /* ID from the DIV I want to grab data from    */

      var myUrl = $(this).attr("href", "retrieveLastNames.php") +   ".deptPeople";
      $(".rightColumn").load(myUrl);
        return false;
       });

      });
```

The toggleLetters class is attached to each link(letter of the alphabet) retrieveLastNames.php is the second page that I am trying to load from. deptPeople is the ul I am trying to pull in from the second page, and rightColumn is the div that I am trying to load my list into. Right now, when I click on a letter the page does not go to retrieveLastNames.php, so I know that my jQuery is doing SOMETHING since its knowing to not load the other page. The question is, why is it not pulling in my list?

**Update**

Peter's solution worked for me to get the ul to display in the page, however, now my results are not filtering.

```
<?php
$lastnameFilter = $_GET["lastnameFilter"];
$data = $_GET['page1Data'];
// 1. import connection to database
require_once("../../db_connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE lastName LIKE '".$lastnameFilter."%'ORDER BY title DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

?>
```

Previously, my links looked like this:

```
<li><a class="toggleLetters" href="retrieveLastNames.php?lastnameFilter="B">B</a></li>
```

I changed them to

```
<li><a class="toggleLetters" href="#" data-url-data="B">B</a></li>
```

Now instead of filtering the names by letter it shows all the names in my database.

Comment: Are you sure your URL is actually ending with `.deptPeople`? Take a look inside `myUrl`

Comment: `var myUrl = $(this).attr("href", "retrieveLastNames.php") +   ".deptPeople";` would probably give you `"[object Object].deptPeople"`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: It doesn't, .deptPeople is a class on my ul.

Comment: Well it's part of your URL now, try `console.log(myUrl);` after `var myUrl = ....` and look in your console.

Comment: The variable `myUrl` should be of type string but you have a mixture of jQuery collection and string. Secondly, `myUrl` should pass along to page two what was selected on page one so as to know how to filter the list.

Comment: You're trying to do too much with too little.  First you want to retreive the page via ajax, parse it to an html object you can JQuery on, then find the UL you want, and only then append it to your current page.  Take things one step at a time.

Comment: Hmm yeah I got [object Object].deptPeople when I tried that.

Comment: I feel we are missing too much information to give a precise answer, to get the HREF, just use `$(this).attr('href');`

Comment: Okay thanks guys, I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: Has the `ul` you're trying to load in got an ID?

Comment: it has a class (.deptPeople)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following may work depending on the structure of your page:

```
<a href="#" class="toggleLetters" data-url-data="A">A</a>

var data = $(this).data('url-data');
$(".rightColumn").load('retrieveLastNames.php?page1Data=' + data + ' ul');
```

The fragment `<ul>.....</ul>`, if found, will be extracted from the response and inserted into the DOM

In page 2 you would need to read the value in `page1Data` and use it to filter your result.

```
$data = $_GET['page1Data'];
```

Please take a look at the section, **Loading Page Fragments** [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

**UPDATE**

Use either option 1 or option 2 as outlined below.

**option 1:** -- Retain your markup

```
<li><a class="toggleLetters" href="retrieveLastNames.php?lastnameFilter="B">B</a></li>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$lastnameFilter = $_GET['lastnameFilter'];

// 1. import connection to database
require_once("../../db_connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE lastName LIKE '".$lastnameFilter."%'ORDER BY title DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

?>
//^^^^^consider changing this to guard against SQL injection attacks!!!!!
```

JS

```
$(".toggleLetters").click(function() {
    var myUrl = this.href +   " .deptPeople";
    $(".rightColumn").load(myUrl);
    return false;
});
```

**Option 2:** -- Use date- attribute

```
<li><a class="toggleLetters" href="#" data-url-data="B">B</a></li>
```

PHP

```
//Same as above
```

JS

```
$(".toggleLetters").click(function() {
    var myUrl = 'retrieveLastNames.php?lastnameFilter=' + $(this).data('url-data') +   " .deptPeople";
    $(".rightColumn").load(myUrl);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Peter, you're awesome. That works, only its not filtering my results now but I'm just happy to see something after a day and a half of beating my head against the wall with this.

Comment: Sounds good ... my thinking is that you've got to use what was clicked (data) and passed to page in order to filter. What does your filtering look like?

Comment: Instead of filtering results by what letter their last name starts with, its just showing the entire list of names in the database.

Comment: <?php
 $lastnameFilter = $_GET["lastnameFilter"];
 $data = $_GET['page1Data'];
 // 1. import connection to database
 require_once("../../db_connect.php");

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE lastName LIKE '".$lastnameFilter."%'ORDER BY title DESC";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

?>

Comment: Previously I had <li><a class="toggleLetters" href="retrieveLastNames.php?lastnameFilter=B">B</a></li> but I have # now in the href.

Comment: Please post this as an **update** in your question, together with a sample `a` element so we can review and make appropriate suggestions.

Comment: Oooh I see .. which means that all you needed was ... `myUrl = this.href + ' .deptPeople'` ... *take note of the leading space*.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to using this site, do I just edit my question or is there an actual update question button somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: Just edit your question ... at the bottom add a title, **Update** and add the PHP and other info below that.

Comment: Peter, I went with the first option and it is working. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy!!